# CP entries structure tree view folded (not expanded) by default?

Tags: entries, control-panel, structure

Is there a simple way to display the CP entries structure tree folded (not expanded) by default ?
Because we have a very complex entries tree whith lots of entries and levels and my users needs to fold everything each time they access it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the tree is stored into local storage on the user's browser, so as long as that is not cleared, then the position of each of the nodes should be remembered between requests.

Comment: I guess clearing local storage is a very bad idea or not possible anyway with a Craft plugin?

Comment: Local storage is all saved client side, so it's not accessible via PHP.